# Age boolean in new.erb view and controller with Ruby, PGSql and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, date, view, boolean, sinatra

I'm working with Sinatra and my goal is getting the user of my app to entry their customers' age in the 'create customer' form and accept them as customers if `age >= 21`. `@dob` is an instance variable of the object `customer` and it is a `date`.

My try on the controller:

```
post '/customer' do
  @customer = Customer.new( params )
    if @dob.nil?
            return "No date of Birth"
     else 
            age = Date.today.year - @dob.year
                if age >= 21
                       @customer.save
                       erb( :"guests/create" ) 
                else
                       erb( :"guests/not_created" )
                end        
    end
end
```

The form in the `new.erb` file:

```
<div class="form-el">
     <label for="dob">DOB:</label>
     <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"/>
</div>
```

The error here is `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'year' for nil:NilClass>`, but also changing the `year` method other mistakes occur. 
Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: what line is the error coming from? I don't see how you would get that error with the code you've shown. By the way this type of validation can be refactored on to the Customer model. Which ORM are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any ORM as far as I know. How can I refactor it in Costumer?

Comment: So you defined the save method yourself? What class does Customer inherit from?

Comment: Customer is a class by itself, I defined all the CRUD actions in the model. I was creating the age check there but didn't know how to use it in the views afterwards. 

    if @dob.nil?
          return "No date of Birth"

Is making return "No date of Birth" any date I insert in the 'add customer' form... How can I check the use inserted a date at this point?

Comment: Ok in the future I would recommend you use an ORM such as Active Record - it's not too difficult to set up with Sinatra and will save you a lot of work. See https://github.com/sinatra-activerecord/sinatra-activerecord. Second, is the error really coming from the `age = Date.today.year - @dob.year` line? I don't think that's possible for you go to get a `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'year' for nil:NilClass>` error here if you've already determined `@dob` is non-nil.

Comment: Thanks Max. Now I have no error message from Sinatra but I get the blank page with the message "No date of Birth" any date I add in the form (over 21, under 21 or without adding any date to the form). How can I can check if @dob.nil? The .nil? is not working apparently.

Comment: I don't know what you changed in your code and there is no way nil? Is not working properly. Please show your code. It would also help a lot if you can install a debugger gem like pry and step through your code.

Comment: The error here is pretty obvious. If `@dob` is an instance variable of Customer you can't expect just to leak outside of the object. Thats the whole point of instance variables! You would have to create an accessor so that you can call `customer.dob`.

Comment: Hi Joe. Along with max's suggestion you might also want to change that return to a `halt` with a 4xx error status, or call an `error` handler, you don't `return` from a Sinatra route block. See the [README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Max, the @dob instance variable is amongst the attr_accessor in the Customer model from day 1, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: " the @dob instance variable is amongst the attr_accessor in the Customer model from day 1" - but it's not being *called*. Replace `@dob` with `customer.dob` everywhere (you could even do it inside the Customer class without fear) and see if that changes things.